# Tensorflow Estimator memory usage

Tags: tensorflow

I found that, in this [program](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/multi-class-neural-networks/programming-exercise), TF Estimator paired with Dataset uses unjustifiably huge amount of memory (about 1 GB) and takes tens of minutes, although the batch size is only 10 and the number of iterations is 100.
The code for model initialisation:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier (
  feature_columns=construct_feature_columns(),
  n_classes=10,
  optimizer=my_optimizer,
  config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(keep_checkpoint_max=1)
)
```

Fit procedure invoked:

```
classifier.train(
    input_fn=training_input_fn,
    steps=steps_per_period
)
```

The program classifies a 10k-example MNIST dataset (~60 MB in memory) with Logistic Regression, while the same process takes only seconds and a bit of memory with sklearn's LogisticRegression. Could anyone please give advice on what the primary memory consumer is here or how I can probably trace the memory usage?

UPD. I carried out another experiment to compare feeding data to the model using placeholders and Dataset class. I implemented a custom logistic regression (as opposed to the one from Estimator) and found out that feeding data using Dataset:

```
ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y))
ds = ds.batch(10).repeat(num_epochs)
ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
x,y = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
...
sess.run(my_optimiser)
```

results in consumption of at least 5x as much memory during the training as with Placeholders:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,784), 'pixels')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None), 'targets')
...
sess.run(my_optimiser, feed_dict={x:train_x, y:train_y})
```

Comment: How did you find 1GB consumption ?

Comment: Only by checking system monitor while I was running the program (I ran it locally)